# How to write to a text file in pipe delimited format from SQL Server / ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, text-formatting

I have a text file which needs to be constantly updated (regular intervals).

All I want is the syntax and possibly some code that outputs data from a SQL Server database using ASP.Net. The code I have so far is :

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<script language="vb" runat="server">
  sub Page_Load(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
  Dim FILENAME as String = Server.MapPath("Output.txt")

    Dim objStreamWriter as StreamWriter
   ' If Len(Dir$(FILENAME)) > 0 Then Kill(FILENAME)
   objStreamWriter = File.AppendText(FILENAME)

    objStreamWriter.WriteLine("A user viewed this demo at: " & DateTime.Now.ToString())

    objStreamWriter.Close()

    Dim objStreamReader as StreamReader
    objStreamReader = File.OpenText(FILENAME)

    Dim contents as String = objStreamReader.ReadToEnd()

    lblNicerOutput.Text = contents.Replace(vbCrLf, "<br>")

    objStreamReader.Close()
  end sub
</script>

<asp:label runat="server" id="lblNicerOutput" Font-Name="Verdana" />
```

With PHP, it is a breeze, but with .Net I have no clue. If you could help me with the database connectivity and **how to write the data in pipe delimited format to an Output.txt file**, that had be awesome. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Dim dr As SqlDataReader

  Dim FILENAME as String = Server.MapPath("Output.txt")

  Dim objStreamWriter as StreamWriter
  objStreamWriter = File.CreateText(FILENAME)

  sqlConn.Open()
   'opening the connection
  myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT  id, title, expirydate, creationdate from tbl where tbl.isactive=1 and getdate()<=ExpiryDate order by  creationdate asc", sqlConn)
  'executing the command and assigning it to connection 
  dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
  While dr.Read()

      objStreamWriter.WriteLine("{0}|{1}|{2:yyyy-MM-dd}|{3:yyyy-MM-dd}", dr(0),  dr(1), dr(2), dr(3))

  End While
  dr.Close()
  sqlConn.Close()

  objStreamWriter.Close()

  Dim objStreamReader as StreamReader
  objStreamReader = File.OpenText(FILENAME)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by at least putting this code into a code-behind file so that your page at least follows the principle of least surprise.

Easiest way to write stuff to a file is to use the [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx) method (assuming your application has appropriate permissions for the file system).

You can access the database using the [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) class and execute whatever commands you need with a [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx).  Once you've gotten data back from the database, just turn it into an array (assuming there's not a massive amount of data) and call [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) method like so `String.Join("|", yourData)`.

Comment: This ASP.Net page doesn't display anything to the user. This is just  a workaround for the limitations with 1and1 (Windows, Linux hosts database incompatibility). So, I don't really care about code behind model. 

Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: Just because you don't care doesn't mean the next guy who has to maintain this page won't care.

Comment: Fair enough, what does the query you want to run look like? (I'll write up a code sample for you to start from).

Comment: The query would be : select id, title, createdate, expirydate from contact where active = 1;

I would like to write these to an Output.txt file (this file is re-created every one hour). 

The Output.txt file would then be processed using PHP (MySQL load INFILE ...).

Thank you so much for your time.